# Split large mbox by sender

Tags: mbox

I 'm looking for a way to split a very large mbox file into several mbox files (one for each sender).

Alternatively, to only extract the messages by a specified sender.

Looking up and down the internet, but have not found any (or used the wrong search terms).

Comment: Last time I had to do something approaching, I ended writing a small Python script. The `mailbox` module allows you to easily split the mbox and filter its content message by message, dealing with the low-level details.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [archmbox](http://adc-archmbox.sourceforge.net/) fits your needs. There also an [article](http://archive09.linux.com/feature/154660) about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Procmail, `formail -s procmail -m simple.rc <mbox` will split the messages in `mbox` into separate folders based on whatever rules you put in `simple.rc`.  (If not, skip down to the Awk alternative.) For example,

```
:0:
* ^From:(.*\<)?(billg|william henry gates)
billg

:0:
* ^From steve@(pixar|next|apple)\.com
steve

:0:
* ^Subject: I for one welcome our new lizard overlords
lizard

:0:
unmatched
```

will apply the three regular expressions in order, and divert the incoming message to the corresponding mbox folder for the first one which matched. The final delivery is unconditional, and takes care of any messages which were not matched by a condition.

The single concept "sender" is not well-defined; there are many different fields you could examine which will sometimes return different results depending on how exactly the message was sent. Trivially, the `From:` header should usually contain the sender's name and address (but some people use different email clients which format this information differently on different occasions, and sometimes use multiple addresses) but there are at least nominally scenarios where you should examine `Sender:` or `Resent-From:` or the envelope sender (called `From_` in Procmail circles) instead, or as well.

`formail -s program args <mbox` simply reads `mbox` and splits it into individual messages, and runs `program args` on each extracted message in turn, passing in the message as standard input.

If the envelope sender in the mbox separator is accurate enough to sort the messages on (hint: try

```
LC_ALL=C sed -n '/^From /!d;s///;s/ .*//p' mbox |
sort | uniq -c | sort -r -n >senders
```

and examine the resulting `senders` file to see what envelope sender addresses are in there. The `LC_ALL=C` might not be necessary but should prevent a Unicode `sed` from complaining about non-UTF-8 input) you could use a simple Awk script to split the messages:

```sh
awk '/^From / {
        if (NR>1) close output
        if ($2 ~ /billg|whgates/) output="billg"
        else if ($2 ~ /steve@(pixar|next|apple)/ output="steve"
        else if ($2 ~ /lizard-l@lizzserv/) output="lizard"
        else output="unmatched"}
    { print >>output }' mbox
```